# Does "COPY . /your/directory" on Dockerfile Copy The Dockerfile It Self?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and Dockerfile, still learning a lot of. But I have a question quite  simple but still didn't find the answer for that.
I'm following several tutorials, more specifically the ones at [Katakoda](https://www.katacoda.com).
The command (on Dockerfile) `COPY. /usr/share/nginx/html`is said to

> copies the content of the current directory into a particular location
>   inside the container.

But this includes the `Dockerfile` itself? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

`COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html`

Above statement in Dockerfile will copy all the contents in your current directory on the docker host to `/usr/share/nginx/html` inside docker container.

You can use `.dockerignore` if you want anything to be ignored by docker while copying etc.

In case you just want static files to be copied, put them in a different directory and use it in Dockerfile -

`COPY ./app /usr/share/nginx/html`